# Replacement of deprecated setUserState() and getUserState()

Tags: joomla-api, joomla-3.7

I have just noticed that methods setUserState() and getUserState() from JApplication are marked as deprecated.

But what are the replacements for these two methods ?

Thanks by advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are not deprecated, it's Joomla's documentation that is not perfect.

If you see https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/JFactory.html#method_getApplication

You can notice that it returns `JApplicationCms` and on this object it is not deprecated. You will also notice that it says to look at `\JApplication` for more information, but this object is deprecated. Just call the right object.

`$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$app->getUserState();`

Next time you better click on the reference of the returned object and not the link it says to see for more details :)